# How do I send SQL logs to Symfony WebProfiler?

Tags: php, symfony

I've started working on a Symfony project that uses its own DB utility to execute queries.

I am wondering if the WebProfiler has an event that I can fire when a query is run, to get a SQL log in the profiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must [implement a DataCollector](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/data_collector.html).